# Port issue problem in Deluge

Tags: 21.04, bittorrent, deluge

I cannot download my torrents through Deluge. I have the "Port Issue" problem. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Perhaps open that port in your router? This isn't OS related, of course.

Comment: What, precisely, is "the port issue"? Are there any error messages or error logs? What command are you using? See `https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask`